# Deploying Java EE Web App in specified domain on GlassFish Server

Tags: java, deployment, dns, glassfish

I have a Java Web Application to deploy on GlassFish Server. For this purpose, I created new domain in Glassfish using command `asadmin create-domain`.

How can I deploy my application in this specific domain?

Answer (score 1):

Once the domain has been started, any interaction with the running server will apply to that domain, for example:

```
asadmin create-domain myDomain
asadmin start-domain myDomain
```

Your Domain Admin Server (DAS) will now be running. Deploying to this via asadmin will apply to that domain:

```
asadmin deploy /path/to/my/App.war
```

Or you could visit http://localhost:4848 and deploy using the admin console.

Comment: Hi Mike, The last **command** `code`asadmin deploy /path/to/my/App.war`code` fails with error message _italic_Command deploy only accepts one operand_italic_.

Comment: What is the exact thing you are typing? It looks like you might have got a space in your path or in your application name (which would be common in Windows). If that's the case. surround the whole path and file in quotes

Comment: I tried with quotes and it works now. Thank you Mike